# Are there any other mages (beyond Raistlin) known for being able to "cheat" on the Test of High Sorcery?

Tags: dragonlance

When Raistlin approaches his Test at the Tower of the High Sorcery,

> He is almost about to fail, his life force shattered beyond saving. Then, the wizard-lich Fistandantilus offers him a deal: his life force in exchange for the power to pass the Test. Raistlin accepts, passes the Test, and then reneges on his bargain with Fistandantilus.

Then, years later, when Palin is taking his Test, Dalamar calls an illusion of Raistlin and

> Raistlin himself shows up and chats with Palin.

I haven't been able to find much else about other wizards Tests' details.

Are there any other wizards known for being able to call on supernatural or external help during their Test of the High Sorcery?

Comment: I don't know that I'd call what he did cheating.  He just changed the conditions of the test.  They should have given him a commendation for original thinking.

Comment: I actually think that everything about the test is weird. Raistlin was the best wizard Krynn has ever seen, and he was about to fail the test... Also, I don't think it is that helpful to test what they what to test (is a world that welcomes Black Robes, after all). That's why I wanted some further research about it and thought about this question. I don't know if he changed the conditions or what he really did.

Comment: I don't think he would have been the most powerful wizard in Dragonlance if he hadn't originally made the bargain with Fistandantilus.

Comment: Good point. He needed the external help to survive. Yet, he was the youngest wizard ever to take the Test and was pretty talented. Was he unfairly called for the Test too early? Then ParSalian curses him (hourglass eyes) but also gives him a powerful artifact (staff of Magius)... So the Conclave is doing pretty much what they want, and maybe their Test is not useful for what they think it is (weed out those who are not serious about the Art)

Comment: Raistlin is called to the test because he's deemed having become too powerful not be subject to the rule of one of the three gods. Fisto only teaches him a spell that easily kills the elves. The golden armor is, admittedly, Raist's own doing. I don't recall an account of anyone else's Test, period.

Comment: The test of is nephew, Palin, is covered in another novel.  A test which allowed Raistlin to escape the Abyss.

Comment: @Mazura, well, there are some details here and there about Palin's and Dalamar's Test, but not much. I read this books more that a decade ago, and left with the arrival of the Fifth Age. I was hoping somebody could give some clue about other characters I might not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, after some (more) research, I'm positive this question can be answered with "**No**, there are no wizards (beyond Raistlin, if we consider Fistandantilus' help as *cheating*) known for being able to call on external or supernatural help on their Test of High Sorcery".

There is lack of evidence that that happened. If somebody ever is able to prove otherwise, please say so and we'll revisit this question.

Comment: There was a storyline in the Meeting Sextet about a failed wizard who was helped out by Chemosh and became a renegade. Actually the supplementary books, while not the same level of canon as the original books by Weiss/Hickman, mention a lot of renegade mages, who either failed the test but did not die, or went into hiding and did not take the test at all.